# "static" UISearchBar extends it's margins to UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` on my `UITableView`, here's the layout: 
[image]

Please note, I do not what `UISearchBar` to hide my `UINavigationBar` when searching!

When I start searching `UISearchBar` kind of extends it's margins to `UITableView`. Here's the preview of 2 states: 
[image]

Here's the video preview: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14522796/SearchBarExtends2.mov

The questions are: **Why this happens and how to prevent this?**
Thanks.

Comment: select your `viewcontroller->attribute inspector->uncheck adjust scroll view insects`

Comment: @Bhavin I tried this on the whole view controller hierarchy - did not helped!

Comment: As i know its the natural behavior of it.. To prevent it you need to set -20 to your tableView's y origin.. and set it back after searching.. hmm..

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
          UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44.0)];
      searchBar.autoresizingMask =0;
       searchBar.delegate = self;
       searchBar.placeholder = @"Search for items...";
        searchBar.showsScopeBar=YES;

   UIView *searchBarWrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
searchBarWrapper.autoresizingMask = 0;
[searchBarWrapper addSubview:searchBar];



[searchbar  sizeToFit]; //[searchbar= your objectname]
```

Comment: Setting autoresizingMask to 0 did not helped!